# Reference saved inputs in file name when saving .xls or .prn from VBA (Is it possible to include?)

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula, vba

Following code below works on copying range and pasting in new files. Files are saved as .xls and .prn.

Is it possible to reference a defined range or cell to include in the naming convention?

Would like to include defined range after "Official" and "Document" (ie - Official 29-74A - Document A/B/C/etc.)

Is it as easy as adding something like:

& "! DocName " after "Official"
and
& "! DocRev " after "Document"

Any suggestions appreciated.

Code:
    Sub()

```
    Range("C13:F82").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells.Select
    Selections.ColumnWidth = 14
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ChDir "C:\temp"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=
        "C:\temp\Official - Document.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
        password:="", WriteResPassword:="",ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:-False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=
        "C:\temp\Official - Document.prn", FileFormat:= _
        xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include information from a Range on an Excel sheet by referencing that Range. But it will help a lot if the code more exactly identifies what it's working with. The code in the question relies a lot on selecting things and what the current selection is. The sample below doesn't try to correct all of that, just the most important items for the stated question.

1. Specify each workbook with an object variable. That way there's less chance of a mix-up.
2. Assuming the cell(s) with file name information have been selected and a `Name` applied, that can be called using the `Range` property and assigned to a string variable.
3. The string variable is then concatenated to the static file name using `&`.

Sample code:

```
Dim wbSource as Excel.Workbook
Dim wbTarget as Excel.Workbook
Dim sDocName as String
Set wbSouce = ActiveWorkbook
sDocName = wbSource.ActiveSheet.Range("DocName").Value
' This is the first workbook, not the new one
'Do other things
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
'Do other things
wbTarget.SaveAs Filename:=
    "C:\temp\Official " & sDocName & "- Document.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
    password:="", WriteResPassword:="",ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:-False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"C:\temp\Official -"& Range("C13:F82").address &" Document.xls"
```

Comment: I think it is better to replace "**:**" in the address with "**-**" or something similar to avoid illegal file name. Say if Rng is the range then  `Replace(Rng.Address, ":", "-")` or to more simple filename without dollar mark with `Replace(Rng.Address(False, False, , True), ":", "-")`

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't make a lot of sense. In what way would getting a Range's address, which is anyway hard-coded into the Range specification, answer the question? The question is how to get the value in a defined range (specific cell, not an array of cells). On Stack Overflow it's also desirable to add some explanation of *why* a contribution is relevant to the question - in what way it solves the problem.